# Is this MEMBER-BOOKING-COURT design in 3rd Normal Form?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization, 3nf

I'm a student and new to database design. I've got this requirement:

[image]

Here's my answer (primary key is in bold):

MEMBER (**Member number**, member firstname, member surname)

BOOKING (**Member number + Court number**, booking date, booking time)

COURT (**Member number + Court number**, duration, payment)

Is my solution in 3rd normal form yet? And does **Member number + Court number** make an appropriate composite key for the COURT table?

**Member number + Court number** is already the key for BOOKING, which is a weak entity here I think. The reason I chose Member number + Court number as the composite key for COURT table is that Court number can be repeated so it doesn't make a very good primary key for the table.

Comment: You need to read an introduction to normalization. Normalization to 3NF is about decomposition according to functional dependencies. Yet your reasoning here has nothing to do with that. So you clearly need to find out what normalization involves.

Comment: "A member is only allowed to book one court at a time" is not clear. You need to ask your teachers how they want you to interpret it. It doesn't mean that a given member can only have one booking in the table, because the example data contradicts that. Maybe they are trying to say that a given a court and a date and a time there can only be one booking. Maybe they are trying to say that given a member and a date there can only be one booking.

Comment: I've clarified with my lecturer, he said that the condition is at given a member and a date there can only be one booking, which is exactly what you said. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No.

Think about what uniquely identifies a "court". And every attribute of "court" needs to be dependent on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key.

I think an candidate key for "court" would be something like "court number".

And a "court" doesn't have a duration... a "booking" has a duration. A "court" doesn't have a payment, a "booking" has a payment.

---

For "booking", I don't think you have a valid candidate key.

It depends on the interpretation/clarification of the "only one court at a time" rule/constraint.  Seems to me that rule is saying that at a given date and time, a member can reserve at most one court.  That is, a member can reserve a court for 3pm on Wednesday, and court for 10am on Saturday... but a member cannot reserve *two* courts for 10am on Saturday.

To help enforce that, you would probably want a unique constraint on the tuple `(member_number,booking_date,booking_time)`. Maybe that's a candidate key for "booking".

(To fully enforce the "one court at a time" rule, there would be some additional logic involved, beyond that unique constraint. To prevent member Sally from booking a court at 10AM on Saturday for 2 hours, and another court at 11AM (that same Saturday) for 1 hour. The unique constraint by itself wouldn't prevent Sally from having *two* courts booked from 11AM to noon.)

---

An alternative (or additional) interpretation would be that a "court" can be "booked" by *at most* one member at a given time. That suggest a unique constraint on the booking entity...  on the `(court_number,booking_date,booking_time)` tuple.

Again, the same issue with overlapping periods, different start times but a duration long enough that it overlaps another booking. Again, we wouldn't want to allow a single "court" to be booked from 10AM for 2 hours, and also at 11AM for 1 hour.

---

Clarifying these types of requirements with the data owner/system owner is the purpose for "modeling" sessions, which produce a Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) as an artifact of the discovery process.

We would have the data owner clarify the requirements by asking appropriate questions...

What is the minimum duration and maximum duration for a "booking"?

Can two bookings for a single court overlap?  (the 10AM 2 hour, 11AM 1 hour thing)

Is a member allowed to reserve ("book") a court for Tuesday, and Thursday and Saturday?

etc.

We want to be careful that the constraints that we build into the data model are hard and fast rules, real constraints, which are true all of the time.  And not just "Well, that's true most of the time. But Doctor Stevens, we let him book two."

Comment: You would do better to identify the FDs that the example data shows don't hold, then those that the example data plus common sense suggest do or don't hold. Then you can discuss the normalization process. Which so far is not addressed in this answer.

Comment: @philipxy: I believe the candidate key that I identified for the "court" entity, and the two candidate keys for the "booking" entity will satisfy the requirements of 3NF, and are satisfactory for all of the (rather limited) example data provided. You are free to demonstrate how to get to 3NF from a different direction. I'm not a fan of backing into a data model on the base of incomplete example data. Proper modeling means identifying the entities, identifying candidate the keys, exploring the relationships between the entities... doing the actual analysis to discover the requirements.

Comment: @DanielDoan: Apparently, there are some experts that have the ability to back in to a data model by analyzing incomplete example data following a "normalization process". Yes, we would strive for an entity relationship model in 3NF at a minimum. In discovering requirements for a system, I find it's easier to communicate/work with the system stakeholders by starting with identifying each "entity" (person,place,concept,thing or event that 1) can be uniquely identified, 2) is important to the business, and 2) we can store information about".

Comment: @DanieDoan: and requirements are *never* clear enough. They are usually sufficient as starting points for requirements discovery. Once we identify some entities, we can discover the relationships between them by asking appropriate questions... throwing together a scenario... "Dr.Smith wants to reserve a court..." which we can discuss with the system owner to refine the actual requirements. Once we figure out the candidate keys and the cardinality of the relationships, getting the attributes assigned to the proper entities (3NF) tends to be a pretty straightforward exercise.

Comment: ... and another downvote on the answer today. No explanation, no alternative answer, no suggestions. The only critique is from @philipxy, suggesting that a "better" approach is to "identify the functional dependencies" suggested by incomplete example data and "common sense". When a better answer is posted, I will remove my answer. (And as far as the rule about "one court at a time", I have a strong suspicion that once the system is implemented, there will be a suddenly discovered requirement to allow exceptions to that rule. I would be wary of encoding that rule into the database schema.)

Comment: @spencer7593 We have been *given* a 1-table design. We want to *normalize* it. CKs & decompositions are per FDs. Your answer doesn't reflect an understanding of CKs, FDs or normalization, or extract info or ask for clarity in terms relevant to normalization. Eg you claim there are certain CKs but without sound justification. I would close, not answer, the question, because a reasonable answer (as I commented) essentially includes a textbook chapter. I see (as could you) I downvoted here 2 jun 1:20 when I said *normalization "so far is not addressed in this answer"*. It "is not useful".